# pinentry-mac: disable Keychain storage

Tags: gpg, macos, security

I'm using `pinentry-mac` with `openfortivpn`, to prompt for passwords and tokens. I installed both using Homebrew.

However, there's a button in the pinentry dialog to save to the keychain, and it's checked by default. I'd like to disable this, or at least make it unchecked by default.

Based on [this](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/gpg-mail-faq/gpg-mail-hidden-settings#disable-option-to-store-password-in-macos-keychain) and [this](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/60232-save-to-keychain-is-enabled-by-default) and the [source](https://github.com/GPGTools/pinentry/tree/master/macosx), I've tried both of these:

```
defaults write org.gpgtools.common DisableKeychain -bool yes
defaults write org.gpgtools.common UseKeychain false
```

But neither had any effect. Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 4):

You were close, and helped me find the solution.

According to [this](https://github.com/GPGTools/pinentry/blob/master/macosx/AppDelegate.m#L38) line

The correct command is

```
defaults write org.gpgtools.common UseKeychain NO
```

Comment: I still see the Save In Keychain button after running this. How did you install `pinentry`? Are you using it from `openfortivpn` or some other way?

Comment: works for me, thanks. I've installed pinentry-mac with Homebrew